# DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (16/07/2020) at position 0 (1): Unexpected character

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel 5.8 application, I have:

`config/app.php`

```php
'date_format' => 'd/m/Y',
'date_format_js' => 'dd/mm/yy',
```

Model

```php
use Carbon\Carbon;

class HrHolidayDate extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'hr_holiday_dates';

    protected $fillable = [
        'holiday_name',
        'holiday_date',

    ];

    protected $dates = [
        'holiday_date'
    ];


    protected $casts = [];


    public function setHolidayDateAttribute($input)
    {
        $this->attributes['holiday_date'] =
            Carbon::createFromFormat(config('app.date_format'), $input)->format('Y-m-d');
    }


    public function getHolidayDateAttribute($input)
    {
        return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $input)
            ->format(config('app.date_format'));
    }
}
```

I tried to format it in the Blae view as shown below:

`view`

```html
@foreach($holidays as $key => $holiday)
    <td>
        {{Carbon\Carbon::parse($holiday->holiday_date)->format('d-m-Y') ?? '' }}
    </td>
@endforeach
```

When I wanted to render the view blade, I got this error:

> [2020-07-15 11:57:56] production.ERROR: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (16/07/2020) at position 0 (1): Unexpected character (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelapp\resources\views\hr\holiday_dates\index.blade.php) {"userId":466,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (16/07/2020) at position 0 (1): Unexpected character (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelapp
> esources\views\hr\holiday_dates\index.blade.php) at C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelapp\vendor
> esbot\carbon\src\Carbon\Traits\Creator.php:81, Exception(code: 0): DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (16/07/2020) at position 0 (1): Unexpected character at C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelapp\vendor
> esbot\carbon\src\Carbon\Traits\Creator.php:81)
> [stacktrace]

How do I resolve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because Carbon does not understand `d/m/Y` format out of the box. If you use slashes it should be `mm/dd/yyyy` in that case. `d/m/Y` is not an official date format.

You can use :

```
{{ Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $holiday->holiday_date)->format('d-m-Y') }}
```

Comment: When I used       {{ Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('dd/mm/yy', $holiday->holiday_date)->format('d-m-Y') }}     I got this error:      [2020-07-15 12:27:26] production.ERROR: Unexpected data found.
Data missing (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelapp\resources\views\hr\holiday_dates\index.blade.php) {"userId":466,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Unexpected data found.
Data missing (View: C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\laravelapp\
esources\\views\\hr\\holiday_dates\\index.blade.php) at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\laravelapp\\vendor\

Comment: here `createFromFormat('dd/mm/yy', $holiday->holiday_date)` need to match with your `$holiday->holiday_date format`

Comment: How do you mean? I don't understand

Comment: whats  the date format of `$holiday->holiday_date` ?

Comment: `d-m-Y` is your expected format. I need this variable date format `$holiday->holiday_date` ? or what is the output of `{{ $holiday->holiday_date }}` ?

Comment: 16/07/2020 This is the expected output

Comment: @mikefolu what is your current output with `{{ $holiday->holiday_date }}` ?

Comment: When I used just {{ $holiday->holiday_date ?? '' }}   I got this output without error:  16/07/2020

Comment: Try with this `{{ Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $holiday->holiday_date)->format('d-m-Y') }}`